# ¿Por qué la variable no adquiere el valor dentro del bloque en Swift?

Tags: swift, swift4

Estoy probando un código en [swift](/questions/tagged/swift).

En el bloque que hace la petición de un JSON a una URL yo intento modificar el valor de `mText`, pero no asume el valor. La idea era leer el JSON, construir un contenido y mostrarlo en el `textView`. Pero no funciona, y no es problema de la petición, la misma funciona y el `print` me muestra el JSON en consola. Incluso intento setear un valor a mano y tampoco lo admite. Si seteo cualquier cosa fuera de ese bloque si lo reconoce, pero dentro la variable no es modificada.

¿A qué se debe eso? ¿Cómo podría modificar el textView desde dentro de la petición?

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bodyText: UITextView!

    var detailName: String?
    var mText: String?
    var mURL: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mURL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/yfua8"
        if let url = URL(string: mURL!) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print(jsonString)
                        self.mText="lorem";//jsonString
                    }
                }
                }.resume()
        }

        title = detailName
        bodyText.text = mURL
        //bodyText.text = mText *Queda en blanco*
        detailImage.image = UIImage.init(named: detailName!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Comment: te devuelve algo  esta funcion URLSession.shared.d?

Comment: Aqui puede que ocurra algo, el completion se ejecuta después de que le ingresas el bodyText.text = mText  cuando mText es Nil por eso te aparece blanco... usa break points y observa el comportamiento de lo que estas haciendo en el URLSession... te recomiendo colocar uno en self.mText = jsonString... y otro en bodyText.text = mText.... por otro lado... simplemente no estas recibiendo los datos del jsonString..

Answer (score 0):

Trata con la devolucion de esta funcion: `URLSession.shared.dataTask`

algo asi:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask

task.data
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No creas que soy muy diestro en Switch, apenas estoy balbuceando código en este lenguaje. ¿Cómo se adaptaría esto en mi contexto?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que la petición a la api de  red se realiza de manera asíncrona al resto de tu código. Es decir, cuando vas a utilizar la variable en la que quieres guardar los datos de la api, estos datos aún no han sido guardados en la variable.
Una solución sería realizar lo que quieras hacer con esa variable una vez sea seteada, de la siguiente manera:

```
var mURL: String? {
    didSet {
        //acciones a realizar
    }
}
```

De esta manera te aseguras que tu variable realice las acciones sólo cuando tenga datos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es por que la petición se hace de manera asíncrona, de tal manera que cuando tratas de asignar esa propiedad aun el servicio no te responde, debes cambiar el texto de tu label dentro de tu peticion no sin antes cambiarte al hilo principal con

```
if let url = URL(string: mURL!) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print(jsonString)
                        self.mText="lorem";//jsonString
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            bodyText.text = jsonString
                        }
                    }
                }
                }.resume()
        }
```